# When leaving Spring transactional context, result is not returned even though exception was handled

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

Say we have the following case:

```
public class Caller {
    @Autowired EntryService service;

    // will return JSON
    @Action
    public Result getResut() {
        Result result = service.doStuff(a);
        // return statement is not reachable in case of exc
        return result;
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class EntryService {

    @Autowired Handler handler;

    public Result doStuff(Args a) {
        try {
            return handler.handle(a);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return Result.errorEntry();
        }
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class Handler {
    public Result handle(Arg a) {
        // some stuff
        return result
    }
}
```

I have a strange problem: when exception happens in handler, tx is marked as rollback-only and exception is handled in entrySrervice - result representing processing error should be returned, but it is not!

DoStuff caller (non-tx), it's struts action, does not receive error result, actually it is totally skipped and after doStuff returns error result caller is not called at all.

What did I miss?

Is it the case, that when I leave spring tx context and tx is marked as roll-back return clause is discarded?

**UPDATE**
Added Caller class.
The fix for the problem is to apply REQUIRES_NEW propagation to Handler. The question *why* still remains.

Comment: Which line exactly you think that should get called but is not?

Comment: I expect to receive Result.errorEntry in caller but debugger does not even stop there. Caller was not shown in this code example but it is struts action.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional information to your post by using the [edit] functionality. But please [don't pollute your post with `EDIT:` or `UPDATE:` sections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post). For future readers, posts need to be standalone, without any history. These sites are not forums, but intend to be libraries of canonical, high-quality, questions and answers. Future readers are not helped by seeing all kind of history.